# What is the character limit for UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

What is the character limit for the iOS Picker? I am in process of designing a web app, and we are using currencies which can be awfully long.

I know iOS will automatically truncate and add a "..." to the end, but I need to find out how many characters fit before being truncated.

[image: Image showing sample iOS picker]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the picker size, the font and the specific characters. You will need to test it yourself for your specific specifications...

Comment: Can you specify any of that in a web app?